# How to alter width of movieclip in slider from parent

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, slider, movieclip

I have a slider component setup in my flash app. This slider has a few extra movieclips that I have created.

From the parent timeline, I would like to change the width of one of those movieclips in my slider.

I can't just access the child movieclip like I usually would (`slider_mc.other_mc.width`) because it sits in a slider so it gives me this error:

> ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property other_mc not found on
>   fl.controls.Slider and there is no default value.     at
>   play_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()

Does anyone know how I could do this?

Thanks

EDIT:

Just to explain further:

the slider component is a movieclip with the instance name `slider_mc` and `other_mc` sits inside the slider movieclip. I need to alter `other_mc`'s width from the parent movieclip.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

You need to listen to events from the Slider. Something like this should work if both the slider and other mc are in the same timeline

```
import fl.events.SliderEvent;

slider_mc.addEventListener(SliderEvent.THUMB_DRAG, thumbDragHandler);

function thumbDragHandler(event:SliderEvent):void {
    other_mc.width = event.value;
}
```

Comment: I think you've slightly misunderstood. The `other_mc` is in the `slider_mc`. I want to alter `other_mc` from the parent. The code you supplied wont work as `other_mc` is not in the parent. Originally, I should just be able to do `slider_mc.other_mc.width` but because `slider_mc` is a slider component, it's not working.

Comment: Ahh ok I'm not sure how or why you would put an mc inside the slider component, but I guess the issue is that other_mc is not part of the Slider component's Class definition. Using MovieClip(slider_mc).other_mc or slider_mc["other_mc"] might give you the access you want